# How to solve the execption "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 3" when launching a task from SCDF?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run a Spring batch jar through SCDF. I use different datasource fpr both reading and writing(Both Oracle DB). The dataSource I use to write is primary datasource. I use a Custom Build SCDF to include oracle driver dependencies. Below is the custom SCDF project location.

[dataflow-server-22x](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/custom-dataflow-builds/dataflow-server-22x)

I my local Spring batch project I implemented DefaultTaskConfigurer to provide my primary datasource. So when I run the Batch project from IDE the project runs fine and it reads records from secondary datasource and writes into primary datasource. But when I deploy the batch jar to custom build SCDF as task and launch it, I get an error that says,

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TaskExecution, ID 3 not found
```

When I checked the task Execution table (which can be accessed via primary datasource), the task execution ID is there in the table. But still I get this error. For each each run a new task Id is inserted into Task_execution table but I get the above error message with newly inserted task_execution id.
Below are the project specifics:

```
Spring-boot-starter-parent : 2.2.5.RELEASE.
Spring-cloud-dataflow : 2.2.0.RELEASE.
```

I load all of my Batch_jobs from main class of Boot using the instance of batch job class and only the main class (which kickstarts all jobs)contains @EnableTask annotation. Below is my class structure.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableScheduling
    @EnableTask
    public class SpringBootMainApplication{
        @Autowired
        Job1Loader job1Loader;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMainApplication.class, args);
        }

        @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 * * * ?")
        public void executeJob1Loader() throws Exception
        {
            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                        .addString("JobID",         
                                     String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                                        .toJobParameters();
            jobLauncher.run(job1Loader.loadJob1(), param);
        }
    }

    //Job Config
    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class Job1Loader {
    @Bean
        public Job loadJob1()
        {
            return jobBuilderFactory().get("JOb1Loader")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step01())
                .end()
                .build();;//return job
    }
```

I use two different datasources in my Spring job project, both are oracle datasource(Different servers).I marked one of them as primary and used that Datasource in my custom implementation of "DefaultTaskConfigurer" as below.

```
@Configuration
public class TaskConfig extends DefaultTaskConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    DatabaseConfig databaseConfig; 
    @Override
    public DataSource getTaskDataSource() {
        return databaseConfig.dataSource();//dataSource() returns the 
primary ds
    }
}
```

Below are the properties I use in both SCDF custom serer and Spring Batch project.

**UPDATE - 1**

```
**Spring batch Job :**
 spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**MY_PRIMARY_DB**
 spring.datasource.username=db_user
 spring.datasource.password=db_pwd
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**MY_SECONDARY_DB**
 spring.datasource.username=db_user
 spring.datasource.password=db_pwd
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

**SCDF custom Server:**
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@**MY_PRIMARY_DB**
 spring.datasource.username=db_user
 spring.datasource.password=db_pwd
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

My Batch application uses two db configurations. one to Read and one write. 
Because the source and destination are different.
Since the TASK_EXECUTION tables were created in **MY_PRIMARY_DB** database I pass only the primary db configuration for the SCDF to read and write. Because read and write takes place in the same DB.

I tried other answers for this question, But none worked. And as I said earlier,  Any input on this would be of great help. 
Thanks.

Comment: A couple notes:
1. I wouldn't use the scheduler on a task since a task is expected to have an end and by using the `@Scheduled` annotation, you are setting it up to not end.
2. Based on your information, you should have two databases configured for your task.  Is that correct?  Your values above only indicate that the SCDF server is using one configuration and your task is using a different one.

Comment: When launching a task SCDF creates an entry in the task execution table before launching the task.  This entry does not have start nor end time.   When SCDF launches the task it passes the `spring.cloud.task.executionid` property with the execution id it created.   When the task starts it will use that id for update the information about the task execution.   What I'm seeing from your detail in your report is that   SCDF is using one database and your task is using the other.

Comment: @MichaelMinella, I have updated my question with few more comments for better clarity. as stated above, Though my task needs 2 datasources for read and write, the SCDF going to read and write the data of Task_execution from single data source, which i hav given in application.properties. Moreover the scdf inserts the task_execution_id with given datasource, but for some reason it couldn't read it back with same DS.

Comment: Hi @GlennRenfro, How can we instruct the SCDF to use the same datasource to write and fetch the task_execution_id using the Datasource I have configured with ? I thought the taskConfigurer should do the trick. Is there any other configuration I'm missing?

Comment: Have you debugged to confirm that the `DataSource` that your `TaskConfigurer` is returning is the one that SCDF is configuring?  My bet is that it's not.

Comment: Yeah it returns the one it intended to. Because there are two methods each returns different datasource. I have used a method which returns primary daaource in Taskconfigurer.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for your valuable suggestion. I took a look at the task configurer again. Turned out the issue is actually with TaskConfigurer class. When I override DefaultTaskConfigurer.getTaskDataSource() and provide my autowired Datasource dependency as mentioned above it's not working. But when I passed the Datasource to the DefaultTaskConfigurer(Datasource ds) constructor, it's working fine. Any idea why the overriding approach not works? Is the DB config and TaskConfig bean creations happening at the same time, so the task config doesn't see the valid db dependancy ?

Comment: I also removed the @schedule annotation per your suggestion. But here a Single project contains 10 jobs, it raises few more questions for me. 1. Several of them runs at different intervals. How can I schedule them for the locally running jobs? 2. How can I start one job based on result of previous job(Since all are in same project)? Please let me know your inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding the DefaultTaskConfigurer.getTaskDataSource() method as I have done above, I changed the DefaultTaskConfigurer implementation as below. I'm not sure yet why overriding the method getTaskDataSource() is causing the problem. Below is the solution that worked for me.

```
@Configuration
public class TaskConfig extends DefaultTaskConfigurer 
{

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaskConfig.class);

    Autowired
    public TaskConfig(@Qualifier("datasource1") DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource); //"datasource1" is reference to the primary datasource.
    }
}
```